# Shell Script for checking processes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, monitoring

We have around 300 servers (AIX, HP-UX, Suse Linux, RHEL, Solaris) in the environment, which makes it very difficult to check whether a process called syslog is running in these servers or not, individually.

Hence, I am developing a shell script which should ssh in as root from my Linux open client Lenovo Thinkpad and execute the `ps -ef` command and return the ouput in a text file.

```
for i in `cat /tmp/serverlist |awk '{ print $1 }'`
do
    ssh -l root $i `bash -x ./sysloginfo.sh` >>syslogdata.txt
done
```

And the script file sysloginfo.sh contains the following:

```
for i in `ps -ef |grep -i syslog |grep -v pts |grep -v super |awk '{ print $9 }'`
do
    echo "`uname -n`" $i "\n" 
done
```

Now when I execute the command, it says the following for all the servers one by one and returns back my $ prompt of my Linux Laptop Terminal.

```
   bash: xxxxxx.xxxx.com: command not found
   ++ ps -ef
   ++ grep -i syslog
   ++ grep -v pts
   ++ grep -v super
   ++ awk '{ print $9 }'
   + for i in '`ps -ef |grep -i syslog |grep -v pts |grep -v super |awk '\''{ print $9 }'\''`'
   ++ uname -n
   + echo oc7057073017.ibm.com -i '\n'
   + for i in '`ps -ef |grep -i syslog |grep -v pts |grep -v super |awk '\''{ print $9 }'\''`'
   ++ uname -n
   + echo xxxxxx.xxxx.com: --start '\n'
```

Comment: Replace backquotes in `ssh -l root` with single quotes.

Comment: Filter grep out of your process list too. `ps -ef | <your stuff> | grep -ve grep` | awk '{print $9}'.  You can also pass multiple regexes to grep by using -e.  grep -ve pts -ve super -ie syslog .  Some greps will treat all of the arguments as case insensitive regardless of where -i falls so if it matters, separate that one out.

Comment: 300 servers, that would be an application for monitoring like [nagios.org](http://www.nagios.org) ?

Comment: Couple of things, you don't need to be running as root to do this, you shouldn't be using `cat` anywhere, and you have way too many `grep` and `awk` statements. But really, there are a million monitoring tools that do this way better, and even if there weren't you could just run cronjobs on each host and have them all pipe to one location or database on some host.

Comment: Why don't you use any of the monitoring tools like New relic, munin, etc? If you find them overreaching use things like SeaLion. Check this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/293426/system-monitoring-tools-for-ubuntu/) for a gist. This'll simplify your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found out a way to pull out the process in a text file. Please refer to the code below.

```
    for i in `cat /tmp/serverlist`
    do
    echo $i:`ssh -l root $i "uname -n;ps -eo comm | grep -i syslog"` >> sysloginfo.txt
    done
```

And that gives an output as,

```
    xx.xx.xx.xx: xxxxxxx101 syslogd
    xx.xx.xx.xx: xxxxxxx102 syslog-ng
    xx.xx.xx.xx: xxxxxxx103
    xx.xx.xx.xx: xxxxxxx104 syslog-ng syslog-ng
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do all of that ?

If you have snmp installed - use SNMP to query all remote hosts without any SSH  I will try to help out and point you in the right direction:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost 1.3.6.1.2|grep -i syslog
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunName.1171 = STRING: "rsyslogd"
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunPath.1171 = STRING: "/sbin/rsyslogd"
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunParameters.1171 = STRING: "-i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5"
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunParameters.15145 = STRING: "-i syslog"
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWInstalledName.392 = STRING: "rsyslog-5.8.10-6.el6"
```

These are all the stuff related to snmp on this machine

Now running this specific set of snmpwalk commands I can pin point the pid on this local machine but changing localhost to a remote host so long as the password is public and snmp connections are allowed from my host then this should work

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public -Oq localhost HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunName|grep syslog
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunName.1171 "rsyslogd"


 snmpwalk -v2c -c public -Oq localhost HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunName|grep syslog|awk -F"hrSWRunName." '{print $2}'|awk -F" " '{print $1}'
1171
```

The pid is 1171

```
ps auwx|grep 1171
root      1171  0.0  0.0 249276  1820 ?        Sl   Nov20   0:03 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5
```

Comment: This is a production environment and I am not allowed to play around with new ways of entering into a server. All we have is a public key in the server and a private key in our local machine which authenticates us into the host when we enter "ssh -l root <hostname>". I appreciate your help but it would be better if you could help me out fixing the above command to give an output like,

<hostname> - syslog-ng
<hostname> - syslogd

in a text editor. - Thanks

Comment: so, `ssh -l root <hostname> snmpwalk [options] localhost HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunName|grep syslog` .    What happened when you trivially converted VH's recommendation and tried it?